# C - Accessing array of stucts

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have a basic problem that I cannot for the life of me figure out. New to C so bear with me.

First I create an array of structs:

```
struct rule {
    int  *in;       /* ingress flag */
    int  *out;      /* egress flag */
    char *actionvalue;  /* actionvalue BLOCK or UNBLOCK */  
    char *proto;        /* protocol e.g. UDP TCP ICMP */    
    char *ip_src;       /* source and dest address */
    int  *srcport;      /* src port */
    char *net_src;      /* source and dest netmask */   
    char *ip_dst;       /* source and dest address */   
    int  *dstport;      /* dst port */
    char *net_dst;      /* source and dest netmask */   
} rulelist[10];
```

I then assign values to them

```
rulelist[policy_count].in = strsep(&temp, delims);
rulelist[policy_count].out = strsep(&temp, delims); etc...
```

And I can then access them without a problem

`printk("%s", rulelist[policy_count].in);`

However when I go to access the array the array later in the code in another function..

`printk("%s", rulelist[policy_count].in);`

Will crash, like it is derefrencing a null pointer.

I have read a lot about initializing instead of assigning but each example is different and I can't seem to get a good grasp on it.

I also don't understand how I can immediately access it and then not be able to in a different function. The structure is declared globally so I don't believe its a scope problem.

Thanks

Comment: Please always and without exception compile with all compiler warnings enabled (e.g. `-W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wwrite-strings` on GCC), and don't ignore any of the warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `strsep` returns a pointer somehwere in `temp`. Once `temp` becomes invalid (for example when its scope ends) `rulelist[policy_count].in` will point to invalid memory.

So you should probably `malloc` some memory and copy the data. But since you're using `strsep` there's a good chance you already have `strdup`:

```
char *p = strsep(&temp, delims);
rulelist[policy_count].in = strdup(p);
```

Comment: Awesome! I knew I was doing something silly. If I can't use strdup are there any issues with simply doing strcpy(vmalloc( strlen(p) + 1), p) instead?

Comment: @kevgliss Well, `strdup` is implemented using `malloc` and `strcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

Define the struct as:

```
struct rule {
    int  in;       /* ingress flag */
    int  out;      /* egress flag */
    char *actionvalue;  /* actionvalue BLOCK or UNBLOCK */  
    char *proto;        /* protocol e.g. UDP TCP ICMP */    
    char *ip_src;       /* source and dest address */
    int  srcport;      /* src port */
    char *net_src;      /* source and dest netmask */   
    char *ip_dst;       /* source and dest address */   
    int  dstport;      /* dst port */
    char *net_dst;      /* source and dest netmask */   
} rulelist[10];
```

And assign values to them by:

```
rulelist[policy_count].in = atoi(strsep(&temp, delims));
rulelist[policy_count].out = atoi(strsep(&temp, delims)); 
rulelist[policy_count].actionvalue = strdup(strsep(&temp, delims)); 
rulelist[policy_count].proto= strdup(strsep(&temp, delims)); 
...
```

Then you can print int field by:

```
printf("%d", rulelist[policy_count].in);
```

And string field by:

```
printf("%s", rulelist[policy_count].actionvalue);
```

For avoid memory leak, don't forget to free string field by free().